# How to detect a double touch/taps on an Android ListView?

Tags: android

Do you know about how to detect two touches/taps on a `ListView`?

I am trying to have the following method called when double touched:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why aren't you using a Long Touch?  Or are you using that already for something else?  The advantages over a long touch over a double touch:

- Long Press is a recommeded interaction in the UI Guidelines, double touch is not.
- It's what users expect; a user might not find a double touch action as they won't go looking for it
- It's already [handled in the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html).

Comment: Also typically the single tap action on a list item (to open or execute that item) deeply conflicts with whatever a double tap would be.  So to be able to handle a double tap, you'd need to delay executing the single tap action until the double tap timeout passes, resulting in not very responsive UI.

Comment: @hackbod Does waiting for second tap for same amount of time (300ms or so) that `GestureListener` takes to distinguish whats single and whats double tap, makes the UI not responsive?

Comment: ListView doesn't use GestureListener, it does its own touch handling code because there are a lot of deep interactions it needs to deal with for scrolling and such.  If you are saying you are just going to sleep() for 300ms or so...  yes, that makes the UI not responsive, and you really wouldn't want to count on that anyway because once you are done sleeping the order that the pending work (a Message for long press detection and incoming touch events) do not have a clearly defined order and the touch even time stamp is based on when the event was sent.

Comment: @hackbod I did not said I'd go for `sleep(300)` but use another approach like I did here https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DoubleTapListViewHandler I did not go for `sleep()` but used handler to `delay sending of the message that will envoke the custom interface for 300ms`. In that time the UI is not frozen, I guarantee. If you are free and don't believe me check what I did.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

See it here: 
Involving CountDownTimer: https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DoubleTapListView
Involving Handler: 
http://code.google.com/p/double-tap-listview-handler/ 
https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DoubleTapListViewHandler
My brief explaination: http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/how-to-detect-double-taps-on-listview-items-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on using a double tap in your UI, you could always save state in your Actvity or other container.

A simple implementation would be storing the time the touch was registered, and comparing against that on the next touch event to determine if the time lapsed since the second touch falls with in whatever range you are defining a double tab to mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a double tap on a ListView can be totally valid, particularly if it is done over an unoccupied area. For instance I have a diary application listing actions for today. This is already  so that long presses allow actions to be edited or deleted. But left / right touch gestures are used to quickly move to the previous / next day, and a double tap is a shortcut to get back to "today". Is that intuitive? Well, close enough, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think for double tap or touch you have to use GestureDetector and its methods on touch for single and double tap.
here is a link for refrence
http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/715651-make-android-multi-touch-coding-simpler-with-gesturedetector

Comment: Try not to post only a link. Provide additional information

Answer (score 0):

My answer is base on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711833/get-selected-item-when-double-click-on-listview-item),and it work for me.

```
final GestureDetector gestureDectector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureListener());
        listview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
```

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                return false;
            }
            gestureDectector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        int position = listview.pointToPosition((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
        if (position < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "double-click " + mList.get(position).content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        int position = listview.pointToPosition((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
        if (position < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "single-click " + mList.get(position).content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}