# Android ListView Change one Row on double tap

Tags: android, listview, layout, double-click

I have a ListView with some products names. What I have to do is to change the layout of one row when the user performs double-tap on that row, with another layout which has other data regarding the product. Is this possible? If yes, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont if I have understood clearly what you need but it is possible.

1. Make a custom listview (the listview must have all the components needed when double-tapped)
2. At start hide all the components except the textview which has the products name.
3. On double tap show the components of the tap row (visible = true)
Note: As for double tap it is another matter. You should consider Long Press instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works now. My problem was more complex than I have exposed it here, but your idea helped me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

See this question for a similar setup [How to detect a double touch/taps on an Android ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962865/how-to-detect-a-double-touch-taps-on-an-android-listview)

There an answer points to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

If you *really*, *really* want to handle double-click you'll have to handle the `OnClick()` event and count the first click as part of the double click.

Register a delayed handler for the single click action (if there should be one).

When you next receive an `OnClick()` event then calculate the time between that click and the previous one. If it is below some arbitrary threshold then you count it as a double click. Cancel the delayed SingleClick handler and run your DoubleClick Handler.

But it'll be brittle; could confuse the user and will be more difficult to build and maintain.

So, in short, use `OnLongClick()` instead of `OnClick()`. The Twitter app is a good example of the use of this UX.

However, once you've decided how to capture the event [take a look here for a blog post](http://erikw.eu/android-update-single-item-in-listview/) on replacing individual items in a ListView